# AJAX on IE doesnt give result onchange (ONLY IE)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

my code is working on other browser yet on IE they doesnt give any result  once i select my drop down button.but it change and it just give empty result.

this is my ajax

```
$("#book").change(function(){
        var DOMBULK = $("#book").val();
        $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                url: "store/book.php?cc="+DOMBULK, 
                data:{get_option:DOMBULK},
                success: function(result){
                    $("#tybook").html(result);
                }});    
        });
```

book.php

```
<?
$dtacc = $_GET['cc'];
$tybook= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE status = 1 AND parentid ='$dtacc'"); 
while($rowtybook = mysql_fetch_assoc($tybook) or die (mysql_error()))
{ ?> 
<option value='<?=$rowtybook['value']?>'><? =$rowtybook['name']?></option>
<? }  ?>
```

and html

```
<select id='book' name='book'> 
        <? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE status = 1");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
 ?>
 <option value='<?=$row['value']?>'><?=$row['name']?></option> 
 <? 
    } 
 ?>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: look at your developer console

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: developer console doesnt give any error once i select drop button.

Comment: what is the version of IE?

Comment: i use IE version 11.

Comment: does your function trigger when you change the drop down in IE?

Comment: my funtion get trigger but return empty result which actually the result return data. just on IE . on other browser the code is working.

Comment: Not here  edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not printed any thing in `book.php` that is why it's give you the blank response

```
    $dtacc = $_GET['cc'];

    $tybook = "SELECT * FROM store 
            WHERE status = '1' 
            AND parentid ='".$dtacc."' ";

    $pretybook = mysql_query($tybook)   or die(mysql_error());
    $infor = null;
    while($rowtybook = mysql_fetch_array($pretybook)){
        $infor['name'] = $rowtybook['name'];
        $infor['value'] = $rowtybook['value'];
        $data[] = $infor;
    }
    die(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: don't know how your code work on the other browser except IE

Comment: still having same error. no data yet if alert got array of data.

Comment: put console.log in the success callback and test in IE console what is coming like this `success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                }})`

Comment: thanks Aman for helping me out. i turn to use json encode to pass the data back. now its work. plus i learn how to do append today xD

Comment: If this answer is useful then plz award me as green tick or up-vote

Comment: i made some change in your answer and i make some changes in my ajax too.